# Facebook places API: Is it possible to get the place picture?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using Facebook graph API for my iPhone app to get a list of nearby places, I use the "search" request with some parameters. The response I get is a list of places that include info like: "latitude", "longitude", "name", "id"... I also want the picture of this place (the one that ill see if ill go to the place page on Facebook) Is it possible to get this picture with the API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you get the ID of the place from the graph search, the image url is http://graph.facebook.com/id/picture?type=large

Here is an example:
http://graph.facebook.com/141429005897813/picture?type=large

Comment: @OffBySome
I tried that too, but couldn't see results. Either ways, if it's working for you, kool!